# Pop up onload for scamming mirror domain

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to have a popup show up on a site that's mirroring a site I control, but not show up on the site that I control?

Background info:

A site I work on, Safam.com, is being mirrored by another site, greaseonbroadway.com. I assume this is some sort of odd mistake, but the fact is that greaseonbroadway has the top listings in google when searching for Safam. I've notified google about this, but I don't know if or when anything will be done. In the meantime I've set an htaccess command to break links on greaseonbroadway. This is mildly effective, but not really what I want. I need people to know they're on the wrong site and redirect them to the Safam.com site.

In the htaccess code I put the message in the link "GreaseOnBroadway.com_is_spoofing_Safam.com___Please_Go_Directly_To_Safam.com", but I doubt it helps much. What I'd like to do is have a popup show up on greaseonbroadway but not show up on safam.com. I know the information will be automatically mirrored as I've set a div (supposed to be a popup, didn't work) to say "Click Here to make sure you're on SAFAM.COM". Screenshot on greaseonbroadway: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GRlCA.png and screenshot on safam.com: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wPwuY.png

Comment: As a forward, I don't have much experience with this, but do you know 'how' they are downloading your site?  What I mean to say is.. there should be something in your access logs, so you can just deny the specific IP of that host.

Answer (score 2):

You can completely block the site from accessing yours. For instance, try this:

```
if( location.hostname.toLowerCase() != "safam.com") {
    document.body.innerHTML = "<p>This site is illegally mirroring <a href="http://safam.com/">Safam.com</a>!</p>";
}
```